# Get scope-variable value via ng-init + ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

I can't figure out why the variable that I am trying to fetch from controller via *ng-repeat* block has wrong value.

**Situation :** I am trying to invoke the function *getCurrentArray()* with some Integer value. I pass it through singlePost.ID variable (created by ng-repeat), which has proper value just before invoke, as well as after just after invoke. Regardless of that, the variable respondArray (which is simply set by invoked function) is different. Description is simplified to clarify the problem.

**Question :** How to retrieve proper value from controller?

**FULL CODE :** https://plnkr.co/edit/ViK0GmeHFxTeIA8BYWTC?p=preview

**Code :**

- singlePost.ID is simply integer value (1,2 or 3)

CONTROLLER -

```
 self.respondArray = null;

 self.getCurrentArray = function (postID)
 {
     self.respondArray = postID;
     console.log(postID);  // proper value
     console.log(self.respondArray);  // proper value
 }
```

HTML -

```
<div ng-repeat="singlePost in postCtrl.postsArray">
    ...
    VALUE BEFORE INVOKE : {{singlePost.ID}}  // proper value
    <div ng-init="postCtrl.getCurrentArray(singlePost.ID)"></div>
    VALUE READ FROM CONTROLLER : {{postCtrl.respondArray}}  // bad value!
    VALUE AFTER INVOKE : {{singlePost.ID}}  // proper value
    <div ng-repeat="singleResp in postCtrl.respondArray">
        ...  // bad value too!
    </div>
</div>
```

Probably I've done some obvious mistake, but already running out of stream, so I hope, that someone will be able to help.

Comment: I'd recommend creating a plnkr for this, because the code provided doesn't actually define what it is you're looking to do.  I think it's generally a bad idea to use `ng-init`, so if you can get a sample of what you're doing as well as an explanation of what you want it to do, I'm sure I could help you out.

Comment: @ChrisStanley I've just added the code snippet for mentioned problem. Hope it will clarify my issuse :)

Comment: Your plunker is working fine. Try logging the `postID` in `self.getCurrentArray` function. It logs 3 and 2. What issue are you facing exactly?

Comment: @Anubhav Function is getting proper values as you mentioned, however the second loop : 'ng-repeat="singleResp in postCtrl.respondArray' is not iterating at all - respondArray variable seems to remain 'null' regardless the fact that function is changing its value on every ng-repeat iteration.